# How to solve the differential equation below?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

I am solving Linear Algebra and stuck in these kind of model problems.

> Let $V$ be the set of all real valued functions $y = f(x)$ satisfying $y'''-7y'-6y=0$. Show that $V (\Bbb {R})$ is a 3-dimensional real vector space. Write Basis of this vector space.

How to solve the above Differential Equation and proceed further?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  To find a basis, say $y=e^{ax}$ and solve for $a$

Comment: Is it $-6y $ or $ 6y $?

Comment: Sir , It is -6y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linear differential equation with constant coefficients.

If we assume $y=e^{ax}$, we get $(a^3-7a-6)e^{ax}=0$.

Since $e^{ax}\ne0$, that means $\color{blue}{a^3-7a-6=0}$.

Say the solutions to that $\color{blue}{\text{cubic equation}}$ are $a_1, a_2$, and $a_3$.

Then $y=e^{a_1x}, e^{a_2x}$, and $e^{a_3x}$ are solutions to the differential equation.

Since this is a homogenous differential equation,

any linear combination of solutions will also be a solution.

The general solution is thus $y=c_1e^{a_1x}+c_2e^{a_2x}+c_3e^{a_3x}$.

Comment: Thank you sir for the response . Just wanted to clarify , the starting assumption of y=f(x) is to be done on intuition by observing the differential equation ?

Comment: This is the solution for a [homogenous linear differential equation with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equation_with_constant_coefficients)

Comment: @HarshVardhanSingh Look up heaviside operator method